# Mp3s open in Google play after tapping always, have already reset all app preferences. What now?

Tags: default-applications, firefox-for-android

Thanks for not scrolling by after the first half. This happens in Firefox, irrespective of which site used. The first time it offered the choice of downloading using play or downloads. Naturally I clicked the app I'd be opening it in. Now it just opens the file. After resetting the app preferences three time and closing both promhams after resetting and before trying again. With no obvious solution in Firefox settings. I'm out. Do any of you have any suggestions? Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the Firefox address bar, enter `about:config`.
2. search for `download.preferred`.
3. After the search had filtered some items, You will see a preference named `browser.download.preferred.audio/mpeg` whose value is probably `com.google.android.music`.
4. Tap the `Reset` button at the lower right corner of this preference.

Future tip:
To see preferences you modified yourself, enter `about:support`, and check under `Important Modified Preferences`.