# Download .mp3 instead of playing them in firefox for android?

Tags: firefox-for-android, mp3

Firefox on android auto-plays .mp3 links as you click them. How do I download them instead of immediately playing?

Comment: Your question is possibly answered in https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/114956/mp3s-open-in-google-play-after-tapping-always-have-already-reset-all-app-prefer/114960#114960. The only difference is that in section 3 the value won't necessarily be `com.google.android.music`

Comment: Thanks - well, it didn't really work. Clicking "reset" actually removed the whole preference browser.download.preferred.audio/mpeg completely. But .mp3 links are still played in browser internally. And for clarity, I don't want to open it with any app immediately. The purpose is to download the file for playing offline.

Comment: BTW, at least on current versions of Firefox Mobile the integrated player has an option to actually download the file (long tap over the player and look into the menu that is shown).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. In the Firefox address bar, enter `about:config`.
2. Search for `media.play-stand-alone`.
3. You can see `true` below the item's name.
4. Tap the item's name (not on the search bar).
5. A `Toggle` option has appeared at the bottom right. Tap it once. Notice the `true` has changed to `false`
6. Now, when you'll tap on a .mp3 link, Firefox will prompt you with a `Complete action using` dialogue. To download the file, choose `Download`.

Comment: I didnt see any true below the items name.i cant do it at all.i really wish i can.is it not possible on android phone? Is it only for computers?

Comment: I just checked it again using firefox 57.0 on Android 8.0.0, and the answer still stands. Could you describe what you see?